# 17.10 - Firefox slow after ugrade

Tags: upgrade, firefox, 17.10

I have recently upgraded from Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10. After the upgrade, Firefox has become very slow when loading pages. Once a page has loaded everything is as usual (for instance, YouTube plays fine) and the menus are responsive but loading a page takes several seconds. As a comparison, Google Chrome is quite fast.

I'm using Firefox 57.0.1 64-bit. I've already tried clearing the cache and site data, removing it (`apt-get purge firefox` then deleting the remaining files in the Home folder) and reinstalling through the command line but nothing changed.

I would be very grateful for any advice. If nothing works I can always do a clean install of 17.04 (I had to install Unity on 17.10 anyway because the experimental fractional scaling on GNOME didn't work well) but I would rather not have to set up everything again. Thank you very much!

**Update:** Removing Firefox and installing the version provided directly by Mozilla following [these instructions](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-firefox-linux) did not help.

Comment: @lamrub3n  Thank you for the edit, but the package ***is called `firefox`*** with a lowercase `f`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was with Firefox itself rather than Ubuntu. I suppose Firefox must have been updated after the upgrade to 17.10.

I had a look at [Mozilla's instructions for when Firefox can't open websites while other browsers can](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-cant-load-websites-other-browsers-can) and disabling IPv6 did the trick. Using the page loading time plugins from [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22144676/3330422) to measure performance, Firefox and Chrome now have similar loading times, even if the latter is often slightly faster.